# Code first approach to defining a many-to-many relationship results in the mssql error about "cycles or multiple cascade paths"

Tags: sql-server, many-to-many, entity-framework-core, cascade, ef-core-2.2

I am trying to create some tables in my database using Code First approach, and I need a Many-To-Many relationship there too.

Here's the definition of my entities:

```cs
public class User
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<UserCourse> UserCourses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<UserCourse> UserCourses { get; set; }
}

public class UserCourse
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

Then I had to tell EF Core that I wanted it to be a M-M relationship:

```cs
// set many-to-many relationship between user and course

modelBuilder.Entity<UserCourse>()
    .HasKey(uc => new {uc.UserId, uc.CourseId});

modelBuilder.Entity<UserCourse>()
    .HasOne(uc => uc.User)
    .WithMany(u => u.UserCourses)
    .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UserId);

modelBuilder.Entity<UserCourse>()
    .HasOne(uc => uc.Course)
    .WithMany(c => c.UserCourses)
    .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.CourseId);
```

I didn't specify DeleteBehavior for my entities, so SQL Server gave me the error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_UsersCourses_Users_UserId' on table 'UsersCourses' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

So I looked for some solutions and found out that I had to specify the DeleteBehaviour. I did that like so:

```cs
// set ondelete to be restrict

modelBuilder.Entity<UserCourse>()
     .HasOne(uc => uc.User)
     .WithMany(u => u.UserCourses)
     .Metadata.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;

modelBuilder.Entity<UserCourse>()
     .HasOne(uc => uc.Course)
     .WithMany(c => c.UserCourses)
     .Metadata.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
```

Although SQL Server asked me to change OnDelete to NO ACTION, There was no NO ACTION in the DeleteBehavior enum. Instead, tho, it is in the ReferentialAction enum, which is a enum for migrations, so I can't touch it manually (I mean it would seem to be a bad-design decision). People in the internets say that Restrict is exactly what i'm looking for here. Ok. Well, then the problem should be solved, right? Unfortunately, absolutely not.

SQL Server still gives me the same error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_UsersCourses_Users_UserId' on table 'UsersCourses' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

I don't know what to do with that at all. I tried almost everything, although i'm not that experienced in EF Core Code-first approach.

My question is simple: How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting all migrations and initializing a new (first) migration helped me.

In order to do that, perform the following steps:

1. Delete Migrations folder from your project.
2. Delete __EFMigrationsHistory table from DB (drop table __EFMigrationsHistory)
3. Type in the Package Manager Console the following: "Add-Migration Initial"
4. Type in the Package Manager Console the following: "update-database"